# Распознавание символов и работа с изображенями

Tags: c#, изображения, нейронные-сети

Имеется нейронная сеть, способная распознавать символы. При загрузке рисунка из Paint размеров 150 на 150 всё работает нормально.Фон здесь белый, буква нарисована чёрным цветом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При загрузке картинки ( также 150 на 150) с прозрачным фоном программа работает "наоборот"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для удобства понимания вывел цвета пикселей( во втором случае первый пиксель, который является прозрачным, почему-то распознаётся как чёрный, а чёрный соответственно не является почему-то чёрным).

Первая и вторая картинка имеет одинаковый формат .png

Каким образом можно настроить программу для работы с изображением на прозрачном фоне?

Метод считывания картинки

```
public void get(Bitmap map) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mbut.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mbut.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                Color col = map.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (col.R == 0 && col.B == 0 && col.G == 0)
                    mbut[x, y] = true;
                else label9.Text = "Цвет пикселя номер " + x + ":" + y+" "+ Convert.ToString(map.GetPixel(x, y));
            }
        }     
        label10.Text = "Цвет первого пикселя: " + Convert.ToString(map.GetPixel(0, 0));
    }
```

Метод прорисовки весов

```
 public void draw(int n)
    {
        using (Bitmap map = new Bitmap(150, 150))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < weight.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < weight.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    if (weight[x, y] > 1)
                    {                            
                        map.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                    }         
                }
            }
            map.Save(String.Format("Pictures/{0}.png",n), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как вы загружаете изображение в приложение?

Comment: @V.Dmitriy кнопкой "загрузить картинку" открываю диалоговое окно и выбираю изображение

Comment: а значение Weight откуда получаете в последнем листинге?

Comment: @V.Dmitriy вызываю этот метод draw у каждого нейрона, значения Weight берутся у каждого нейрона

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH по какому мануалу делали? (спрашиваю на будущее вдруг пригодиться)

Comment: @NMD такие приложения проще писать с помощью opencv на c++ или ее аналога emgucv для c#. Там и нейронка и метод опорный векторов прикручены и бинаризаторы что-бы в такие ситуации не попасть. По этим библиотекам куча мануалов

Comment: @V.Dmitriy спасибо за ответ! может литературу годную подскажите по opencv? тема эта всегда была интересна, но вот не знаю с чего начать( (кажется Вы в этой теме неплохо разбираетесь)

Comment: @NMD вот отличный мануал с примерами и картинками. :) В нем и книга хорошая указана. Я по ним изучал библиотеку. http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/264.html

Comment: @V.Dmitriy Спасибо!

Comment: @NMD успехов в изучении! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предполагаю что проблема в работе с каналами цветного изображения в цветовой схеме `ARGB`. 
Когда Paint сохраняет изображение, он приводит её к `RGB` и проблем не возникает.
При других редакторах цветовая схема остается `ARGB`.

Вот какая складывается ситуация:

Вы берете цветовой схемы, в первом случае это `RGB`, и по каналу `R` определяете черный это или не черный. В итоге инициализация проходит успешно.

Во втором случае с схемой `ARGB`, в которой изображение имеет прозрачность, первым каналом является `A - alpha(оно-же прозрачность)` вы пытаетесь по прозрачным цветам определить черный и сталкиваетесь с ситуацией когда все пиксели которые прозрачны - получают черный цвет а те которые не прозрачны остаются белыми. В этом и кроется секрет вашей хитроумной инверсии :)

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> if (col.R == 0 && col.B == 0 && col.G == 0)
> ```

Не хватает проверки `&& col.A != 0`. Видимо, paint сохранил прозрачный фон всеми ноликами.